# Is there a difference between using a period to indicate relative path vs $PSScriptRoot?

Tags: powershell

I've been referencing files in my scripts with a period to indicate the current execution directory of the script, such as ".\images\test.png" but I've discovered that I could also point to the same file with $PSScriptRoot\images\test.png.

Is there an argument to be made for one over the other? When using the PS ISE, the former requires that I CD into my script directory before running code, but the scripts will normally be run automatically so the PWD should always be localized in scope. Is there another case I'm not considering?

ED: I suppose I should have specified that I am asking in the case of an independent script that is executed in isolation (it's invoked directly and does not invoke other scripts), which probably leads to the edge case of the current location and location of the current script are one in the same. In less specific conditions that I failed to consider, I can see more divergence.

Comment: `.` means "current location," but `$PSScriptRoot` means "location of the currently executing script." Those two are not the same thing.

Comment: Except for when they are the same simply as a matter of coincidence or intended design.

Comment: Regardless, assuming that they are the same is a path to dissatisfaction.

Comment: Also, prior to v3, $PSScriptRoot is only valid in modules

Comment: Other than those things, they are virtually identical :)

Comment: Good points, I suppose I should have specified that I am asking in the case of an independent script that is executed in isolation (it's invoked directly and does not invoke other scripts), which probably leads to the edge case of the current location and location of the current script are one in the same. In less specific conditions that I failed to consider, I can see more divergence.

Comment: If you can guarantee that they are equal then IMO there is no advantage to one over the other.

Comment: Other than making yoour code less portable of course

Comment: Just to be clear, as @Bill_Stewart shows in his answer, it is possible (I would even say likely) that . and $PSScriptRoot are different. Not invoking other scripts doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct answer to your question as to "is there a difference" is yes, there is a substantial difference.

The difference is that `.` is a reference to the current location. If the current location is a different location than where the script is, then it will not be the same as `$PSScriptRoot`. For example:

```
PS C:\> C:\Scripts\Test-Script.ps1
```

Inside `Test-Script.ps1`, `.` will refer to `C:\` but `$PSScriptRoot` will refer to `C:\Scripts`.